# AWS ECS capacity provider using Terraform v 0.11.10

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I am using terraform version 0.11.10, I am trying to provision an aws ecs capacity provider but getting the following error:

**Error: module.mod.aws_ecs_capacity_provider.ecs: Provider doesn't support resource: aws_ecs_capacity_provider**

I could not find any terraform docs for version 0.11

Does terraform version 0.11.10 supports capacity provider?

Comment: The AWS provider is versioned separately from terraform itself. According to the provider's changelog that resource was added in version 2.42.0 (December 13, 2019): https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: @mjgpy3 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After updating the aws provider version the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS provider is versioned separately from terraform itself. According to the provider's changelog that resource was added in [version 2.42.0 (December 13, 2019)](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2240-august-15-2019).

For more information on provider versions I would checkout the [terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/providers.html#provider-versions).

In short, you may need to pin the AWS provider to a newer version than you're currently using. Pinning is described in the linked documentation.